# Headlight and Indicators on the handlebar OR on the front panel of the Scooter that you drive?

Tags: design, physical, dashboard

There are 3 designs existing now:

1. Headlight and indicator lights both on the handle.
2. Headlight on the handle but indicator lights on the front panel.
3. Headlight and indicator lights both on the front panel.

Which one is a more practical approach towards designing the above?

Comment: Are you asking about the position of the lights themselves, the indicators that tell the rider which lights are on or the controls to switch those lights on and off?

Comment: Yes, I am asking about the positions of the lights on the body or handle of the scooters.

Comment: The question was not at all about the headlights and indicator lights' controls in the handlebar. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are technical reasons for putting a headlight on the panels instead of on the handlebar.

1. There is more room for the wiring
2. The thicker wiring for the headlights to draw power from the electrical system can be compromised by the constant left/right turning.
3. positioning the headlight on the frame means that you are free to design the headlight to be larger in size
4. the headlight moves less erratically in relation to other vehicles and therefore is less likely to dazzle other users

Comment: The switch doesn't havet to handle the current of the headlight. Even in older models, that was done with a relay which could just as easily be far from the switch.

Comment: No but the headlamp does, so if the lamp is onthe handlebar you need thicker gauge wire and ensure that the thicker wire doesnt rub.

Comment: Thank you for the technical breakdown of the reasons of modern scooter designs. Though Companies like Piaggio-Vespa are still having scooters appealing to a mass segment continuing with their oldlegacy designs of having the headlight on the handlebar. I sense its more of style and a retro look.